# Hashing password in MVC 5 application web.config necessary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it necessary to hash the user name and password in the connection string in the web.conifg file? I've read yes and no.  If so, what is the best/easiest way to do this?  I'm a little tentative to do this because the site is already hosted.

Comment: To clarify, are you talking about **database connection strings**? Note that you cannot store hashes of your database password in your connection string as the client needs the original full un/pw; but if you're using Microsoft SQL Server then I strongly suggest using SSPI (Trusted connection) instead.

Comment: I wouldn't say "necessary", but "recommended"? Yes. At the end of the day, Web.config is just a plain-text file, and storing any password in plain-text is never a good idea. Now, to get at it, someone would have to actually breach your server, but you always have to consider that as a possibility. Many security best practices are useless for anything but making your life more difficult 99.9% of the time; it's that 0.1% where it saves your hide that makes it worthwhile.

Comment: Yes I am referring to the database connection string. I'm connecting to GoDaddy's SQL server.